# anothers "class, id" on Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Someone can help me, please? I'm using js to add more line and delete the current line on my application, but it won't running cause of name with lines qty['+i+'], unit['+i+'] and expect_delv_date['+i+']. if i delete those 3 lines it will be running well, but i need those 3 lines for 3 value. I think my problem is js on js. :) please your help master ...
here's my script :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $jn = jQuery.noConflict();
var i = 1;
$jn(function(){
$jn("#addRow").click(function(){
  row = '<box>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-6"><label>Item Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name['+i+']" placeholder="what kind of item is this?"/></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-6"><label>Remarks</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks['+i+']" placeholder="what purpose of this item?"/></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-6"><label>Item Specification</label><textarea class="form-control" name="spec['+i+']" rows="2" placeholder="insert your item specifications ... "></textarea></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-warning col-xs-6"><label>Service Detail</label><textarea class="form-control" name="service_desc['+i+']" rows="2" placeholder="please fill this field if your requested for service!"></textarea></div>'+

  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-1"><label>Qty</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty['+i+']" data-inputmask='"mask":"999"'data-mask/></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-2"><label>Unit</label><select class="chosen-select" style="width:130px;" tabindex="2" name="unit['+i+']"><?php foreach ($unit as $row) { ?><option><option value="<?php echo $row -> desc; ?>"> <?php echo $row -> desc; ?>  </option></option><?php } ?></select></div>'+
  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-3"><label>Expect Date Delivery</label><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation"  name="expect_delv_date['+i+']"/></div></div>'+

  '<div class="form-group has-error col-xs-3"><label for="exampleInputFile">Add an attachment?</label><input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="attach['+i+']"><p class="help-block">max file size is 5MB</p></div>'+
  '<input type="hidden" name="req_by" value="<?php echo $user ['real_name'];?>" />'+
  '<input type="hidden" name="pr_id" value="<?php echo "$pr_id";?>" />'+
  '<div class="form-group col-xs-3"><div class="btn btn-danger pull-right del"><i class="fa fa-minus-square del"></i>&nbsp;delete this item !</div></div>'+
  '</box>';
  $jn(row).insertBefore("#last");
  i++;
  });
});
$jn(".del").live('click', function(){
  $jn(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem I could see is in `data-inputmask='"mask":"999"'data-mask` - it should be `data-inputmask=\'"mask":"999\"'data-mask` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dc3be864/2/

Comment: Dear Razib, it doesn't working ...